# Get array values

Tags: php

I have the following `array` named `$trainer`:

```
Array (
  [0] => stdClass Object (
           [id] => 2
           [firstnamephonetic] =>
           [lastnamephonetic] =>
           [middlename] =>
           [alternatename] =>
           [firstname] => Admin
           [lastname] => User
           [email] => sam@mailinator.com
        )
  [1] => stdClass Object (
           [id] => 4
           [firstnamephonetic] =>
           [lastnamephonetic] =>
           [middlename] =>
           [alternatename] =>
           [firstname] => Bill
           [lastname] => Clinton
           [email] => billclintonteaser2005@mailinator.com
        )
  [2] => stdClass Object (
           [id] => 3
           [firstnamephonetic] =>
           [lastnamephonetic] =>
           [middlename] =>
           [alternatename] =>
           [firstname] => Tom
           [lastname] => Beggins
           [email] => tom@mailinator.com
        )
)
```

How to `get only` the `first` and `lastname` of the `trainers`, so when I want to `display` them it will show them as follow:

> Admin User, Bill Clinton, Tom Beggins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of objects. You need to iterate through each, then obtain with the `->`:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($trainer as $t) {
    $result[] = "$t->firstname $t->lastname";
}
echo implode(', ', $result);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is an array of objects so you can process all the array with a `foreach`
 but then you must address the data in the object using the `->` object notation

```
$line = '';

foreach ( $trainer as $person) {

    $line .= $person->firstname . ' ' . $person->lastname. ', ';
}
echo trim($line, ', ');
```

Or

```
$line = '';

foreach ( $trainer as $person) {

    $line .= sprintf('%s %s, ', 
                     $person->firstname,
                     $person->lastname);
}
echo trim($line, ', ');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
   foreach($trainer as $val){

    echo $val['Name_of_your_index_'];
    // write your code here


    }
```

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, it will help everyone understand your solution with more clarity and for future reference

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
foreach($trainer as $val){
echo $val->firstname."  ". $val->lastname;
}
```

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, it will help everyone understand your solution with more clarity and for future reference.

Comment: array is multidimensional array with standard class object. so i given the above code..